# How to update passed values inside $scope.update?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm passing my values from html like this

```
 <div class='title' editable-text='task.title' buttons='no' onbeforesave="update(task, $data, 'title')">
        {{task.title}}
      </div>
```

Now how do I correctly update its values inside **$scope.update**?

Comment: Do you want to update `task.title`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want to update, but considering it's `$scope.title`, if so, this should work

```
//////////////////update(task, $data, 'title')
$scope.update = function(model, data, key){
    //model === $scope.model, because passed like param
    model[key] = data;
};
```

What's `model[key] = data;`

When dynamically settings props, you cannot do like that

```
var obj = {}; obj.'title' = "hello";
```

But you can do like this

```
var obj = {}; obj['title'] = "hello";
```

As long as your model is object (like obj in example) the `['key']` will refer to property, not index.

Comment: what is [key]? Is that **id**? I want to update **task.title** value